# Xamrin forms carousel view missing reference

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using carousel view in xamarin forms to navigate through pages. After adding packages to my project's xamarin forms folder, I got an error "Cannot load file or assemble xamarin.forms.carouselview or one of its dependencies" I tried loading the assembly in appdelegate.cs. Now am getting a build error **"Reference to type xamarin.forms.IItemViewController claims it is defined assembly xamarin.forms.core, version=1.5.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null, but could be found"** this error is pointing to the code of appdelegate that i have written. 
I will be grateful if i get any suggetions

PS: this works perfect in a sample app. i am getting such error only when i am integrating this in my official project.

Comment: Did you install the NuGet package on both your shared code project as well as the platform project?

Comment: yes i have added..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin Forms CarouselView has a dependency of Xamarin.Forms (>= 2.3.0.42-pre3)

You must upgrade to at least that version or higher. Your Xamarin.Forms.Core dll should then be version=2.0.0 instead of v1.5.0.

Comment: Xamarin.forms version that am using is 2.3.2.127... this version is higher than 2.3.0.42-pre3..

Comment: I think you should double-check on all projects, Adam seems to be right. If you look closely to the error that you got, you notice that there is a version number 1.5.0.0 in there.